# Can I play on other people's buildings in Belfort?

Tags: belfort

I assumed that I can only play on my own buildings.  Are you allowed to play on others' buildings as well in Belfort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you may only play on the buildings that you have built.

You *may* play on a **guild** that has been purchased by another player, paying that player 1 coin.

Comment: *I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the expansion add an ability to play on another players building...  I'll have to go look that up.*